# GET Method Not Allowed: /api/banners in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, get, mixins

I try to use ListModelMixin while getting the list of a queryset. I know I can use **ListAPIView**, but just for the sake of understanding, I use **ListModelMixin**. I called the api but I get Get method is not allowed.

My view:

```
class BannersView(GenericAPIView,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Banners.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:1]
    serializer_class = BannersSerializer
```

My url:

```
path('api/banners',views.BannersView.as_view(),name='api-banners'),
```

Isnt using Listmodelmixin with genericview same as using Listapiview??

Answer (score 1):

No, because `ListAPIView` defines `get` method

From [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L193)

```
class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericAPIView):
    """
    Concrete view for listing a queryset.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You could do the same, but it would be obvious case of reinventing the wheel

Comment: You mean I have to write custom get function like above. I dont really understand the use of mixins then. When do I use this listmodelmixin and when do I use simple listapiview??

Comment: No, you just extend ListAPIView, point of mixins is having reusable methods that can be used in various classes ( in this example list method comes from ListModelMixin) . ListAPIView is not only class in DRF that uses ListModelMixin

Comment: class ListAPIView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericAPIView): Why did you use ListAPIView as a class name?? It can be any name right? Also, we should be using list function inside the code, but you are using get. I dont quite understand.

Comment: This is source of ListAPIView class, not something you should write, as you question is what is the difference between what you have and ListAPIView. it is simply that you do not implement get method